Does ZFS have persistent inode numbers or something similar?
I am wondering if ZFS has persistent inode numbes for files, like EXT does, or if it has something similar with which individual files can be identified even if they are moved or renamed. And will these identifiers (inode number or its ZFS alternative) be respected/stay the same if the dataset is mounted via NFS or SAMBA somewhere?
I am asking because I need to create a program that can scan folders (usually mounted via NFS or SAMBA in this case) and detect when a file is moved or renamed on these mounts.
Basically, the program currently does an ls -Rtil on a mountpoint when it is first mounted and saves the output. From then on, it does an ls -Rtil every hour and checks if the modification date of any files in the output are newer than the timestamp of the last scan. Then it checks if these files have a different name but the same inode number than in the previous scan (rename) or if the inode number was in a different directory in the previous scan (move). On a local EXT4 filesystem this works. Would it also on a ZFS dataset which is NFS/SAMBA mounted somewhere?
Under Linux with EXT4, if I rename and/or move a file on a local filesystem its inode number from ls -i stays the same. I was wondering if that would also be the case on ZFS and if the folder under which the file is located is mounted via NFS or SAMBA? Or possibly, if ZFS has some other unique identifier for files that can be read via some command and which would stay consistent after moving/renaming the file.
Also, would this identifier stay the same across reboots of the underlying server?

What problem does tracking files by inode number solve?  Even on ext4 filesystems using inode number ignores the possibility of file deletion and inode number reuse.  This sounds like an XY problem.  I suspect that you have a problem that you're using file inode number to solve, and you're asking about your solution instead of your actual problem.  To wit:  zfs diff ....

The problem to be solved is to monitor whether files have been renamed or moved within the folder structure. We do not care about deletions, those do not need to be tracked. I believe inode numbers can only be re-used if a file is deleted, right? In that case another file can, by chance, get the inode number of the deleted file. // zfs diff would be an option of course... we would just need to be taking snapshots every hour that we could then diff, that would work!

OpenZFS inode numbers are the internal object id within a dataset. They won't change across true moves (that is, rename() operations) within the same dataset.
